# cannot convert value of parameter date from system string to system datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
public Kupac(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    KupacId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["KupacId"]);
    Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString();
    Prezime = reader["Prezime"].ToString();
    IdentifikacioniBroj = reader["IdentifikacioniBroj"].ToString();
    ClanOd = (DateTime)reader["ClanOd"];
    KorisnickoIme = reader["KorisnickoIme"].ToString();
}

public int KupacId
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Ime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Prezime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string IdentifikacioniBroj
{
    get;
    set;
}

public DateTime ClanOd
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string KorisnickoIme
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: And what the value of the @ClanOd parameter?

Comment: If you post a bit of code - (both C# and SQL) it may help to expedite the answer.

Comment: Date ... i my table ClanOd is smalldatetime

Comment: Post the code that creates this error.  Otherwise we wont be able to help.  And you can lose the bulk of the stack trace too.

Comment: -1 for no code , error is not enough

Comment: @user3332776, post your actual C# code that is throwing this error along with the value for ClanOd that you are trying to pass

Comment: Insert work Delete work...but update don't work for this Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: The method you have posted is not capable of throwing the exception you posted.  But your problem is that you are trying to cast a string to a datetime, and that is not valid.

Comment: Yes I know but how to fix

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a string into a date time but you can use DateTime's Parse:

```
ClanOd = DateTime.Parse(reader["ClanOd"]);
```

Comment: Most likely because the value of the ClanOd parameter is not a valid DateTime string. @user3444160's answer would work in this case. Of if it is a valid string, you might have to specify the culture. Can you post the value of ClanOd when you're trying to convert to DateTime?

Comment: I use for my grid and detailsview DataFormatString {0:dd.MM.yyyy} but not work and i don't know vhere my mistake

Comment: @user3332776 Do **not** say "this not work". Tell us *why* it doesn't work. If there's an exception, try to figure out what the exception means before saying it doesn't work. If you still can't figure it out, then you can let us know.

Answer (score 0):

what Smith.h.Neil said, but I would use the other version of try parse if the value could be an invalid date.

```
 string validDate = "2014-04-17";
 string invalidDate = "not a date";
 DateTime date;
 DateTime date2;
 bool isValidDate = DateTime.TryParse(validDate, out date);
 bool isValidDate2 = DateTime.TryParse(invalidDate , out date2);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Assuming ClanOd is a DateTime Replace

```
ClanOd = (DateTime)reader["ClanOd"];
```

With

```
DateTime date;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(reader["ClanOd"].ToString(), out date);
if(isValid)
    ClanOd  = date;
```

Comment: OP is saying my answer didn't work so I'm guessing the problem would be solved with your answer.

Comment: I must update DetailsView control insert work,delete work but update dont work

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Crap!  Replace Parse with TryParse

Comment: Again mistake Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Is same... evrityng same

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error you are getting now?

Comment: if I'm reading the exception correctly, ClodOd is a string not a DateTime. if that is the case, then you don't need to cast or parse the value to a datetime.  Try "ClanOd = reader["ClanOd"].ToString();"  If that doesn't get rid of the error then you are looking at the wrong code as the source of the exception.

Comment: Compyler say mee Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Bu I dont know why not run in my update method a put debuger and not come to update method?

Comment: You are focused on the wrong code.  The assignment of this property is not the source of exception that you posted before.

Comment: I recommend you debug through it line by line until the exception is thrown.  It is probably the only way you are going to find it.

Comment: of course i try and application break in this code I posted on top debuder not come in Update method...

Comment: Re-post the code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: no exception Just stop execution. there is no code that I put at the top when I click Update. And show me this error Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: I put new code for try catch blocks and put new exeption on top

Comment: Why not allow dynamic update I get the error Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime' BUT when insert data into a table that data does update and is OK ???

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify culture

```
ClanOd = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["ClanOd"], "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Or try this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
ClanOd = DateTime.Parse(reader["ClanOd"], cultureInfo);
```

Comment: no i think this not for mee i think this is some stupid mistake

Comment: replace your ClanOd = (DateTime)reader["ClanOd"]; with code that I provided

Answer (score -1):

This is all from my class KupacAdapter and i thin errror is here somewhere

public class KupacAdapter
{

```
public KupacAdapter()
{

}

public static List<Kupac> VratiKupce(int kriterijumPretrage, string tekstPretrage)
{
    List<Kupac> listaKupaca = new List<Kupac>();

    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand();
        komanda.Connection = konekcija;

        string selectUpit = "select * from Kupac where 1=1 ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tekstPretrage))
        {
            switch (kriterijumPretrage)
            {
                case 0:
                    selectUpit += " and IdentifikacioniBroj LIKE '%' + @kriterijum + '%'";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectUpit += " and Ime LIKE '%' + @kriterijum + '%'";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selectUpit += " and Prezime LIKE '%' + @kriterijum + '%'";
                    break;
            }

            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kriterijum", tekstPretrage);
        }
        komanda.CommandText = selectUpit;


        SqlDataReader reader = komanda.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listaKupaca.Add(new Kupac(reader));
        }
        reader.Close();

        return listaKupaca;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}

public static void InsertKupac(Kupac kupac)
{
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        string insertUpit = "INSERT INTO Kupac(Ime, Prezime, IdentifikacioniBroj, ClanOd, KorisnickoIme) "
                            + "VALUES(@Ime, @Prezime, @IdentifikacioniBroj, GETDATE(), @KorisnickoIme)";

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(insertUpit, konekcija);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ime", kupac.Ime);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezime", kupac.Prezime);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdentifikacioniBroj", kupac.IdentifikacioniBroj);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KorisnickoIme", kupac.KorisnickoIme);

        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}

public static void UpdateKupac(Kupac kupac)
{
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        string updateUpit = @" UPDATE [Kupac] 
                               SET [Ime] = @Ime, [Prezime] = @Prezime, 
                    [IdentifikacioniBroj] = @IdentifikacioniBroj
                               WHERE [KupacId] = @KupacId";

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(updateUpit, konekcija);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@Ime", kupac.Ime);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@Prezime", kupac.Prezime);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@IdentifikacioniBroj", kupac.IdentifikacioniBroj);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@KupacId", kupac.KupacId);

        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}

public static void DeleteKupac(Kupac kupac)
{
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        string deleteUpit = @" DELETE 
                               FROM Kupac
                               WHERE KupacId = @KupacId";

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(deleteUpit, konekcija);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@KupacId", kupac.KupacId);

        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}

public static DataTable VratiSveKupce()
{
    DataTable dtSviKupci = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        string selectUpit = @"SELECT        KupacId, Ime, Prezime, IdentifikacioniBroj, ClanOd,
                            Ime + ' ' + Prezime + ' - ' + IdentifikacioniBroj AS PunoIme

                            FROM            Kupac
                            Order by Ime, Prezime, IdentifikacioniBroj";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectUpit, konekcija);
        da.Fill(dtSviKupci);
    }
    catch
    {
        dtSviKupci = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
    return dtSviKupci;
}

public static int VratiKupacIdZaKorisnickoIme(string korisnickoIme)
{
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand();
        komanda.Connection = konekcija;

        string selectUpit = "select * from Kupac where KorisnickoIme=@KorisnickoIme";
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KorisnickoIme", korisnickoIme);
        komanda.CommandText = selectUpit;

        return Convert.ToInt32(komanda.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

public Kupac( SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            KupacId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["KupacId"]);
            Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString();
            Prezime = reader["Prezime"].ToString();
            IdentifikacioniBroj = reader["IdentifikacioniBroj"].ToString();
            ClanOd = (DateTime)reader["ClanOd"];
            KorisnickoIme = reader["KorisnickoIme"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
    }

```
//public Kupac(SqlDataReader reader)
//{
//    KupacId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["KupacId"]);
//    Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString();
//    Prezime = reader["Prezime"].ToString();
//    IdentifikacioniBroj = reader["IdentifikacioniBroj"].ToString();
//    ClanOd = (DateTime) reader["ClanOd"];        
//    KorisnickoIme = reader["KorisnickoIme"].ToString();
//}

public int KupacId
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Ime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Prezime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string IdentifikacioniBroj
{
    get;
    set;
}

public DateTime ClanOd
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string KorisnickoIme
{
    get;
    set;

}
```

}

Comment: Stop posting random code as answers if it's not an answer. If it is an answer, then provide an explanation with it. Please delete your answers and update your question to appropriately explain your situation.