# Dynamic entry in the SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Why do I get error when I insert one row of data into database, and this data I correctly update but I dynamic insert in database and get update not work.... please tell me WHY I'm confused?

I get this information

> Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime']
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ConvertType(Object value, Type type, String paramName, ParsingCulture parsingCulture) +416
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.BuildObjectValue(Object value, Type destinationType, String paramName, ParsingCulture parsingCulture) +166
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.BuildDataObject(Type dataObjectType, IDictionary inputParameters) +210
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +1276
>      System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +87
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleUpdate(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +1091
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +425
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +89
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +80
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9528682
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Comment: Please post the code causing the exception.  This will allow us to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Well, first, you should try where is defined this parameter in your code. Then post the code that use that parameter. (And don't repost the same question over and over)

Comment: Not duplicate i try another data.. diferent...I'm confused..dynamic not work insert into update works

Comment: @Steve I found where the error is not clear to me why not dynamically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143623/cannot-convert-value-of-parameter-date-from-system-string-to-system-datetime

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to put a `string` value into a `datetime` column. 
Convert your string to a datetime, or change the column to a string column.

```
Cannot convert value of parameter 'ClanOd' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'
```

Comment: Has already been said but he seems unable to find where is used this parameter.

Comment: It's the same when I put the number in the field where the number is. But ClanOD field is readonly.When you insert your hand into the database directly you can do update. I use detailsviev insert works delete works but not dynamically update

Comment: do i change update method? but this ClanOD is readonly not change