# dataformatstring format date Asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I must get only date not and time but gridView show me and time is incorect...I don't know why show me and times? I put DataFormatString {0:d} for only date show me?
Not show me curent value from my field ClanOd is date in database

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ClanOd" HeaderText="Clan od" 
SortExpression="ClanOd" HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" >
```

public Kupac(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        KupacId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["KupacId"]);
        Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString();
        Prezime = reader["Prezime"].ToString();
        IdentifikacioniBroj = reader["IdentifikacioniBroj"].ToString();
        ClanOd = reader["ClanOd"].ToString();
        KorisnickoIme = reader["KorisnickoIme"].ToString();

```
}

public int KupacId
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Ime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Prezime
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string IdentifikacioniBroj
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string ClanOd
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string KorisnickoIme
{
    get;
    set;

}
```

}

Comment: Seems ok to me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: not a good show 22.04.2014. 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The "d" custom format specifier represents the day of the month as a
>   number from 1 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted without a
>   leading zero.
>
> If the "d" format specifier is used without other custom format
>   specifiers, it is interpreted as the "d" standard date and time format
>   specifier.

Therefore, if you just want the date, change your format. The link I provided gives you all the info. Let's say you want it like `12/31/1990` (December 31st of 1990), try this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ClanOd" HeaderText="Clan od" 
SortExpression="ClanOd" HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" 
InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" >
```

Comment: I try but show me again time {0:MM/dd/yyyy} 18.03.2014. 0:00:00

Comment: What I have provided you is correct, it's straight out of the documentation. Make sure that you're probably refreshing your files (are you deploying to a server?) and that the code I'm provided is what you're using.

Comment: In sql server field is date but i dont know hway show time

Comment: When you pull a date from a SQL Server database, it gets converted to the .NET `DateTime` object, which includes a time component. The time component can be ignored. When you format it for display, you just use a format that doesn't show time as I provided in my question. Your comments make me believe that you haven't properly tried the code that I have provided. Make sure you try it. You might need to set up a simple test case to isolate your problem.

Comment: I try and I'm cofused what's wrogng? <asp:BoundField DataField="ClanOd" HeaderText="Clan od" 
                    SortExpression="ClanOd" HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />

Comment: The code you just posted should work. Therefore, something is wrong with your build. Please pay attention to what I'm saying so I don't have to repeat myself: make sure that your server is running the correct version of your code.

Comment: public Kupac(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        KupacId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["KupacId"]);
        Ime = reader["Ime"].ToString();
        Prezime = reader["Prezime"].ToString();
        IdentifikacioniBroj = reader["IdentifikacioniBroj"].ToString();
        ClanOd = reader["ClanOd"].ToString();
        KorisnickoIme = reader["KorisnickoIme"].ToString();
    } public string ClanOD{ get set} datafield is date in sql

Comment: You've converted `ClanOd` to a string? Why? It's a date. Only convert dates to strings when you are displaying it to the client. Use [GetDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx) instead and change `ClanOd` to a DateTime object.

Comment: When I used  ClanOd = (DateTime)reader["ClanOd"]; aplication is broken not can convert System.String to System.DateTime, and I set ClanOD= string, after how me clock and I can't to delete times in my gridView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143623/cannot-convert-value-of-parameter-date-from-system-string-to-system-datetime

Comment: What datatype is `ClanOd` in your database?

Comment: I dont know find solution?

Comment: Sorry, you **really** need to update your question to contain all relevant information. For example, database schema, how you're binding to the database, the class you're using if you're custom binding etc. Please consider that you *should have* included that information from the very beginning.

Comment: In this link is evryting I used in my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143623/cannot-convert-value-of-parameter-date-from-system-string-to-system-datetime.    Field ClanOd is date

Comment: You don't need two questions for the same issue. Close one of them.

Comment: Not two questions i show to evryting to tell me how to fix